# Cut and paste out of/ into text fields in a separate window doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, macos, npapi, cut-and-paste

I have a Macintosh Mozilla plugin which puts up a separate window for login information.
It seems to work fine, it gets keyboard events like typing and hitting
return to hit the default button. HOWEVER, it doesn't seem to get cut
and paste events. When I hit Cmd-v, the edit menu flashes, but nothing
happnes.

Is this a problem with my responder chain? Do I have to specially tell
Mozilla that I want these events? or am I likely to have some other
problem that I haven't even thought of?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem is that I'm using cocoa windows inside Mozilla, which isn't Cocoa... fail.